# How to read variadic function parameters?

Tags: c, pointers, variadic-functions

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int num, ...);

int main(void)
{
  int a=100, b=200, c=300;

  add(1, a);
  add(2, a, b);
  add(3, a, b, c);
  return 0;
}

void add(int num, ...)
{
  int *p=NULL;
  p=&num+1;
  printf("%x \n", p);
  if(num==1)
    {
      printf("%d \n", p[0]);
      printf("num is: %d \n", num);
    }
  else if (num==2)
    {
      printf("%d \n", p[0]+p[1]);
      printf("num is: %d \n", num);
    }
  else
    {
      printf("%d \n", p[0]+p[1]+p[2]);
      printf("num is: %d \n", num);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, `p` initially points to `a`, which is 10. Thus, it should print 10, 30, 60, respectively. Nonetheless, it prints

```
6786db50 
1736891264 
num is: 1 
6786db50 
1736924031 
num is: 2 
6786db50 
1867401241 
num is: 3
```

Is `p` pointing to a wrong address? How can I correctly read the arguments passed as `...`?

Comment: You can make no assumption on how parameters are passed to a function: Why `&num+1` and not `&num-1`? Why even assuming that stack is used? this is not the case on Sparc. You have to use vararg interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you use variadic function calls, you need to use the `va_*` function calls to extract the parameters.

See http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stdarg+3 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D

Answer (score 2):

Your particular example ***may or may not work*** (Works as you expected on my system). You do `p=&num+1;` to access the next element. This holds good under the assumption that the stack is ascending which may not be the case with your architecture. And on many systems, variables upto some limit, are passed on registers than on stack! So your assumption goes wrong totally. Also note the variables can be pushed on to the stack either from left to right or the other way. It is unspecified by the standard.

Hence ***you shouldn't work on assumptions*** and instead use [functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdarg.h.html) designed for this particular use.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am enlightened :)